# jQuery - change style of uncreated div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to *searchengine* for this, but I'm not sure how to call it exactly.

I can change the style of my div elements successfuly, for example:

```
$(document).ready($('div.element1').css("float", "left"));
```

This will successfully change all the elements of class `element1` that exist. However, the new (after above is executed) elements will still spawn with old option of `float: right;`. What is my best/simplest option for permanently changing the style of this `div`? I can inject it manually after the element is created but that feels wrong to be honest.

Comment: You need to actually add the declarations to your CSS and forget about Javascript for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better if you don't add inline style using `.css()` method, but instead just add/remove classes having your style, so create a class for all those elements' style.

If the newly created elements have the class you define, then they will have the style too.

Optionally, you can do this:

```
$(document).on('change or_other_event','your_selectors', function(){
   // your code
});
```

If the new elements have classes `element1`, `element2` ..., you would need something like this:

```
$(document).on('change','div[class*="element"]', function(){
   // your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new class on your css and then add that class to your new element

```
.newElement{
 color:red//example style
}

$("<div>",{class:'newElement'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$(document).ready($('div.element1').css("float", "left"));
```

is equivalent to:

```
var element = $('div.element1').css("float", "left");
$(document).ready(element);
```

This means any un-drawn elements will not be affected. Instead use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div.element1').css("float", "left");
});
```

The above code ensures changes are made once the page has loaded.